# Format Date to human readable within function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I am trying to get to format the date and time or just the date at the moment.

```
function(){
                              var d = new Date();
                              var n = d.getTime();
                              return 'VZW Dfill - ' + n;}
```

What I have tried

```
function(){
                              var d = new Date();
                              return 'VZW Dfill - ' + d;}
```

This returns

```
VZW Dfill - Thu Jan 30 2020 103924 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

I would like the format to be 2020JAN30

I have also tried the following but this does not work

```
function(){
                              var d = new Date('YYYYMDD');
                              return 'VZW Dfill - ' + d;}
```

The above breaks the function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your last function is missing a `'` behind YYYYMDD

Comment: With that function I get (VZW Dfill - Invalid Date.csv)

Comment: Are you using jQuery? It will make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually surprisingly complex using pure JavaScript. Here's one (of many) solutions:

```
var now = new Date();
var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
var formattedDate = now.getFullYear() + months[now.getMonth()] + now.getDate(); 
alert(formattedDate);
```

Using your code from above, write the following function:

```
function(){
                              var d = new Date();
                              var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
                              d = d.getFullYear() + months[d.getMonth()] + d.getDate();
                              return 'VZW Dfill - ' + d;}
```

There is a pretty extensive thread about formatting JavaScript dates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date). Most of them involve (common) third party packages.

Comment: Thank you sir for this.  Works just like i needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also locale

```
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("zh-TW")); // 2020/1/30
```

Comment: OP wanted `YYYYMMMDD`.

Comment: Here it is.. The idea was just to find the right locale that he need :)